# Drawing graphical model without a package

Tags: diagrams

I would like to draw the following graph:
[image]

without using any TikZ style library. I have tried putting `\phantom` to make X and Y aligned, it did not work (don't know why). Additionally, putting multiple alignments `&`, `&&` etc. doesn't work, although it alignes correctly, now graph spans the whole line, which makes it ugly. I would be grateful for a neat solution.

I don't want any libraries because I think of using this in Mathjax.

Comment: I wouldn't use TikZ even if you didn't want to use this with MathJax. Since the diagram is simple I'd use something like `xypic` which provides far easier and more intuitive syntax.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use an `array`, e.g.

```
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
X_0 & \to & X_1 & \to & X_2 & \to & \dots \\
\downarrow && \downarrow && \downarrow \\ 
Y_0 &  & Y_1 &  & Y_2 &  & \dots
\end{array}
```

Testing this on http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/test/sample-dynamic.html gives

[image]

Answer (score 12):

For simple diagrams like these you can use the `amscd` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amscd}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{CD}
X_0 @>>> X_1 @>>> X_2 @>>> \dots \\
@VVV @VVV @VVV \\
Y_0 @. Y_1 @. Y_2 @. \dots
\end{CD}
\]
\end{document}
```

Right, left, down and up arrows are denoted by `@>>>`, `@<<<`, `@VVV` and `@AAA`; an empty arrow is `@.`; an “equal” vertical arrow is `@|`, horizontal is `@=`.

With `@>{f}>>` you get a label `f` above the arrow, with `@>>{f}>` the arrow is below (you can fill both fields), the same for `@<<<`. It is respectively left and right for the vertical arrows `@VVV` and `@AAA`.

[image]

Within MathJax you need `\require{AMScd}`: this is what I get from http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/test/sample-dynamic.html

[image]

Comment: I did not know combining \require with MathJax. This is another great take-home know-how for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

With `matrix` and a horizontal spacing close to the normal one:

```
$$\begin{matrix}
X_0 & \hskip-7pt\rightarrow \hskip-7pt& X_1 & \hskip-7pt\rightarrow\hskip-7pt &X_2 & \hskip-7pt\cdots\\
\downarrow & &\downarrow & &\downarrow \\
Y_0 & &Y_1 & &Y_2 & \hskip-7pt\cdots 
\end{matrix}$$
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A simple use of the `tabbing` environment would suffice:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
$X_0_$ \= $\longrightarrow$ \= $X_1$ \= $\longrightarrow$ \= $X_2$ \= \ldots \\
$\downarrow$ \> \> $\downarrow$ \> \> $\downarrow$\\
$Y_0_$ \> \> $Y_1$ \> \> $Y_2$ \= \ldots \\
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

No packages needed.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this did not work in http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/test/sample-dynamic.html as others did.

Comment: After some Googling, it seems that mathjax doesn't support tabular environments, like tabbing. It will work in a non-mathjax setting, though.